# how to set some work in background when splash screen displayed

Tags: android, backgroundworker

I want to do some work like fill hash-map when splash screen was displayed. but i don't know how i do it

I think one way is create new thread?

code of my splash screen

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    long Delay = 2000;
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
    }

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splashactivity);
        StartAnimations();
        Timer RunSplash = new Timer();

        TimerTask ShowSplash = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                finish();
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginEnquiryTab.class);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_left);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        };

        RunSplash.schedule(ShowSplash,Delay);
    }
```

Comment: what do u want 2 do with the hashmap?

Comment: In splashactivity  fill hasmap with key and value and in some operation i need that info..so i accessed it

Answer (score 1):

Don't create a separate activity for splash screen.
Your splash screen should be on starting activity only.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name="com.architjn.example.ui.activity.MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //do your work here while splash shows..
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Google uses the above way as well.

Comment: Thanx architjn for your rpl..how i open my next activity after splash screen...how i set time for splash screen

Comment: @Varshilshah don't create SplashScreen Activity, don't use timer, all you need is to use MainActivity as your second activity and things you want to do while splashscreen shows can be done before settheme in MainActivity

Comment: i got error     Error:(10, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowBackground'.
 I think this attribute  available from 21 Api

Comment: hey architjn .. your solution worked perfect but i want to display splash for some seconds ..how i do it...curretly image not shown

Comment: use handler for delay and move 3 lines from onCreate() to run()